# Best serial pin to use when you only need an ON/OFF logic

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm coding something for a friend. Now, all I need is an interface to detect a button press and I immediately thought of the serial port. But, I'm afraid I might mess something up when I apply +5V to the wrong pin. (I just need to get the pin state, and when it changes, it triggers an event). Is there a specific pin on the serial port to use (DB9) or is every single one of them safe to use in this case?

Another one: What pin would you recommend? Based on what? (Convenience? or something deeper)

Last one: Does C# really receive a signal from the COM port when something happens? (That would be convenient) Or only when I keep polling for it?

Thanks!

Comment: **DTR** is your friend.  It will remain on until to say otherwise and there is no need to transmit any actual data via the other pins.  _"Does C# really receive a signal from the COM port when something happens?"_ - yes, though you need to be more specific about _something_.

Comment: What if I need to receive on/off signals? (maybe attach a battery to the serial pin/s).

Comment: If you want to read a steady signal, attaching the battery to the PC's **DSR** pin would be one way.

Comment: A DB9 (actually DE-9) connector for a serial port would use EIA/RS-232 signal levels.  So a logic 1 or ON would be a negative 3-12 volts, and a logic 0 or OFF would be positive 3-12 volts.  See [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html)

Comment: I'm gonna grab this opportunity to talk to pros.
Last question: Would that be okay with momentary push buttons? What about if I want to use two of the said buttons? Is it possible to detect a serial pin change on a specific pin?

Comment: @PandaLion98 _"Is it possible to detect a serial pin change on a specific pin?_ - yes. [SerialPort.PinChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.pinchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used to track changes in **DSR** for example.

Comment: Here, have some upvotes.